# Use VSTS/TFS API to get Project type (Agile, Scrum, CMMI)

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I want to use VSTS API to get a list of projects along with the their project type (Agile, Scrum, or CMMI).  Per the documentation [here](https://www.visualstudio.com/docs/integrate/api/tfs/projects).

I am successfully getting a list of projects, but no data is returned about their type.

Comment: You probably want to include your code in your question to improve the chance of getting an answer and avoid downvotes.  Please read [ask] and supply an [mcve]

Comment: @Tibrogargan the problem is not with my code, but rather the capabilities of the API.  Thus, a code sample would only serve to distract the reader and would hinder gaining a solution to the problem.  debugthings answered the question perfectly, keeping his eye on the documentation of the API.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you just want to use the "includeCapabilites" query string when getting a project. This will list out a couple of extra items. Example from API page.

```
"capabilities": {
    "versioncontrol": {
      "sourceControlType": "Tfvc"
    },
    "processTemplate": {
      "templateName": "Microsoft Visual Studio Scrum 2013"
    }
  }
```

https://www.visualstudio.com/docs/integrate/api/tfs/projects#with-capabilities

https://www.visualstudio.com/docs/integrate/api/tfs/processes#get-a-list-of-processes

Comment: With capabilities is just what I was looking for.  I somehow completely missed that when reading through the docs.  Thank you so much!